# How to make sure a typescript module conforms to an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, module

I'm kind of writing a specific content **scraper** for some domains. So for those domains supported I just have some functions declared, let's just say there is a

```
export function getContent(html: string): string {}
```

So, I have many files with this exact interface for example ...

```
export interface Domain {
    supportsHttps: boolean;
    getContent(html: string): string;
}
```

And then for simplicity's sake (to make a map of supported hostname and my domains file), I just

```
// domainsList.ts
import * as domainA from './domains/domainA';

export default {
    "www.domainA.com": domainA,
}
```

Then I import my domain list

```
// index.ts
import * as url from 'url';
import domains from './domainsList';

const maybeDomain: Domain | undefined = domains[url.parse(someUrl).host];

if (maybeDomain) {
    // here I get proper autocompletion ...
    const content = maybeDomain.getContent(someHtml);
} else {
    throw new Error('domain not supported');
}
```

But if I refactor the name of the function in the interface from getContent to getContents for example, I actually do not have any compilation error from inside all the domains files.

I want to ensure ./domains/domainA.ts exported structure conforms to my Domain interface. Do I have a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not actually defining the function have the type of Domain the compiler won't link the two of them together, thus no errors.

Also, the **Domain** interface suits a **class** much better than a function.

You can get all the checks by defining classes instead of functions. Like this:

```js
class AwesomeDomain implements Domain {
    public supportsHttps: boolean;
    getConten(html: string): string {
        return '';
    }
}
```

You can find a full example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Domain%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20supportsHttps%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getConten(html%3A%20string)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AwesomeDomain%20implements%20Domain%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20supportsHttps%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getConten(html%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getConten(html%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but will make it work with a simple object and an interface, no need for classes there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, as long as you expose all of your imports exclusively via an index file export.

module/index.ts

```
import * as A from "./A";
import * as A from "./B";

// type definitions 
export type MyFunc = (args: any[]) => any;
export type MyCollection = {
    [key: string]: MyModule,
}

export interface MyModule {
    KEY: string;

    EXAMPLE_ARRAY: string[];

    someFn: MyFunc;
}

export const COMMANDS = {
    [A.KEY]: A,
    [B.KEY]: B,
} as MyCollection;
```

module/A.ts

```
import { MyFunc } from ".";

export const KEY = "some-key";

export const EXAMPLES = [
    "hello",
    "world",
]

export const someFn: CommandFn = async (args: any[]) => {
    return ''
};
```

If you uncomment one of the exports:

```
Conversion of type '{ "A": typeof A; "B": typeof B; }' to type 'MyCollection' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property '[A.KEY]' is incompatible with index signature.
    Property 'someFn' is missing in type 'typeof import("...") but required in type 'MyModule'.
```